# ruby capitalize doesnt work for the first word of the title

Tags: ruby, capitalize

the code below is to capitalize all words except for 'littleWords' and the first word of the title. (even if it belongs to the littleWords, the first word should be capitalized.)

```
 def titleize (word)
    littleWords = ["and", "the", "over", "or"]

    words = Array.new
    words = word.split(" ")
    titleWords = Array.new

    words.each {|word, index| 
        if index == 0
            word = word.capitalize
        else
            unless littleWords.include?(word)
                word = word.capitalize
            end
        end
        titleWords << word
    }
    return titleWords.join(" ")
end
```

and test code is the below.

```
it "does capitalize 'little words' at the start of a title" do
    expect(titleize("the bridge over the river chao praya")).to eq("The Bridge over         the River chao praya")
  end
```

but it keeps to capitalize the first 'the' as just 'the' instead of 'The'. I wonder which part of my code is wrong. help me... TT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) instead of `each` to get the `index`

Comment: oh my!! it works! thank you so much!! i vote for you.  I guess 'index' doesnt work with 'each' but only with 'each_with_index'?

Comment: Yeah, `each` receives only 1 argument, the value. Also, mark as the correct answer if this solves your problem

Comment: sorry, im so new here, how can i mark as 'correct answer'?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [the documentation of `Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each), it only yields one argument to the block:

```
each { |item| block } → ary
#      ↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

However, your block takes two parameters:

```
words.each {|word, index| 
#           ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Since `each` only yields one argument to the block, the second parameter will always be `nil`. (Unless the element just happens to be an `Array`, then `word` will be bound to the first element of the array and `index` to the second.) And since `index` is always `nil`, it will never equal `0` and thus never enter the first branch of the conditional.

There is, however, another iteration method which actually yields two arguments to the block, the element and its index, it is called [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
words.each_with_index {|word, index| 
#         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

That's all you need to change to make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

Here, another way without using `each` or `each_with_index`.

```
def titleize (word)
    littleWords = ["and", "the", "over", "or"]
    words = word.split(" ")
    words[0].capitalize + " " + words[1..-1].map do |w|
        littleWords.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize
    end.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: thank you so much! i tried to apply this code to one of other codes too. cool :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression and a block.

```
def titlesize(str, little_words)
  str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/) { |w| little_words.include?(w) &
   (Regexp.last_match.begin(0) > 0) ? w : w.capitalize }
end
```

When `little_words` equals the array [<sub><sup>"and", "the", "over", "of"</sup></sub>],

```
titlesize "the days of wine and roses", little_words
  #=> "The Days of Wine and Roses"
```

See [Regexp::last_match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) and [MatchData#begin](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html#method-i-begin). `Regexp.last_match` can be replaced by the global variable `$~`.